# Finding inverse of an int value using Arduino Uno r3

Tags: c, arduino

I am trying to map the value of an `analogRead` from a potentiometer between 0-1. So I do:

```
float inverse_value = 1.0f / (float)analogRead( pot_pin )
```

But when the analogRead of the potentiometer is at 0, the inverse is 0 (which is correct), but when the `analogRead` is at 1023, the inverse becomes `0.0009775170`.

Am I doing the divide correctly or what?

All the circuit is connected correctly. And the Arduino is running properly (I get no errors when uploading).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do, is probably this:

```
float inverse_value = (float)analogRead(pot_pin) / 1023.0f;
```

Assuming the max position is 1023.

That way, 0 to 1023 will be mapped as 0 to 1.

For example, when the potentiometer is in the middle position (512), it becomes this:

```
float inverse_value = 512.0f / 1023.0f;
```

Which is about `0.5`, and probably what you want to get.